# Writing Matrix conversions with Scheme for GIMP

Tags: linux, matrix, scheme, racket, gimp

I want to write some nice Math with DrRacket(R5RS but not only) (Racket Tag is a bit empty).

I would really like to code some matrix stuff like:

(3  3  3)      (5  3  4) 
(4  4  4)  ->  (5  3  4)
(5  5  5)      (5  3  4)

And other stuff like this to set up some nice gimp filters...

Some folks pointed out, this could be done via lists inside lists, but I can't think of a practical example here...

I am looking forward to your reply.
Yours sincerely, Andreas_P

Comment: It's not clear what question you're asking.  Can you rephrase this as a question?

Comment: The linux tag could unnecessarily limit the scope of the question: gimp with script-fu is also available on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

1) what do you mean with Scheme "is built in within the core"? GIMP now has a native Python-fu along with Script-fu

2) the Lisp that won Google AI Challenge is Common Lisp, not Scheme

3) I am not sure, but the Script-fu console states TinyScheme, thus I would expect it to be really essential, with little library support, with respect to more complete Scheme implementations

Anyway, I tried a few example on matrices "the Scheme way". For the sake of simplicity, they lack any control on the input data, but for simple examples they work fine on DrRacket.

```
(define (vect-sum x y)
  (cond 
    ((empty? x) empty)
    (else 
     (cons (+ (first x) (first y)) (vect-sum (rest x) (rest y))))))

(define (scalar-prod a v)
  (cond
    ((empty? v) empty)
    (else
     (cons (* a (first v)) (scalar-prod a (rest v))))))

(define (matr-sum x y)
  (cond
    ((empty? x) empty)
    (else
     (cons (vect-sum (first x) (first y)) 
           (matr-sum (rest x) (rest y))))))

(define (matr-scalar-prod a m)
  (cond
    ((empty? m) empty)
    (else
     (cons (scalar-prod a (first m)) (matr-scalar-prod a (rest m))))))
```

And now a simple test on the data as in the other answer:

```
> (define m '((3 3 3)(5 3 4)(4 4 4)))
> m
'((3 3 3) (5 3 4) (4 4 4))
> (matr-scalar-prod 3 m)
'((9 9 9) (15 9 12) (12 12 12))
```

Answer (score -1):

HHi, I'd highly recommend you to use Python instead of Scheme for writing GIMP scripts, unless you want to learn Scheme for recreational purposes.

One of the tenets in Python is to not allow the language to stay between you and your problem, and writing your own Matrix manipulation code is trivial. If you want high performance ops, you can use a third party library such as NumPy (even from inside GIMP environment) to get it.

So, for a Matrix class that would allow scallar multiplication and adding one could simply write:

```
class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, rows, cols, *args):
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.values = args

    def __getitem__(self, (i,j)):
        return self.values[i * self.cols + j]

    def __setitem__(self,(i,j), value):
        self.values[i * self.cols + j] = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        values = []
        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                values.append(self[i,j] + other[i,j])
        return Matrix(self.rows, self.cols, *values)

    def __mul__(self, N):
        return Matrix(self.rows, self.cols,*(N * v for v in self.values))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "\n".join (" ".join(str(self[i,j]) for j in range(self.cols))   for i in range(self.rows) )
```

Example on Python's interactive console:

```
>>> m = Matrix(3,3,
... 3,3,3,
... 5,3,4,        
... 4,4,4)    
>>> m * 3
9 9 9
15 9 12
12 12 12
```

Implementing more operations is equally simple, and, for calling GIMP's API functions, with this example class, you can just use m.values, that is simply a list with all the matrix values in sequence - which is the way GIMP PDB's functions use them. (Such as pdb.gimp_drawable_transform_matrix or pdb.plug_in_convmatrix. (I suppose you've found GIMP's API browser under the help menu - the same functions are available in Scheme and in Python, just replace the "-" in the names for "_")

Comment: This is just a *teensy* bit flamebait-y... would it be dragging us further into the muck if I were to point to the great language shootout? quick, smileys :) :) :)

Comment: Many Thanks for your kind answer, I have now not much time... but I really want to use Scheme because it is built in within the core and can do many really cool things. (btw: LISP has won Google AI Challenge this year). And I am learning Scheme in my university courses at a somesort of "heavy mode" level. I do love python but can do less than Scheme for now with it... Long answer (and regarding your proposal I want to do very soon). Again many thanks and WOW: How many GIMP Pros are in here?

Comment: This last comment was meant to JSBueno